# Get the specific value from the JSON string or object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an error message like following

```
Your card is declined due to "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": \"card_declined\",\n    \"decline_code\": \"insufficient_funds\",\n    \"doc_url\": \"https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/card-declined\",\n    \"message\": \"Your card has insufficient funds.\",\n    \"param\": \"\",\n    \"request_log_url\": \"https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_fhgKiF9C0d1RrK?t=1700727296\",\n    \"type\": \"card_error\"\n  }\n}\n"
```

I want to fetch the value of `decline_code` that is `insufficient_funds`.

I am trying the below code. It gives me an error like

> Bug in custom code TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decline_code')

can you help me finding he solution as i dont know the javascript just trying from the different stackoverflow posts.

```js
var err = Your card is declined due to "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": \"card_declined\",\n    \"decline_code\": \"insufficient_funds\",\n    \"doc_url\": \"https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/card-declined\",\n    \"message\": \"Your card has insufficient funds.\",\n    \"param\": \"\",\n    \"request_log_url\": \"https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_fhgKiF9C0d1RrK?t=1700727296\",\n    \"type\": \"card_error\"\n  }\n}\n";

let obj = JSON.parse(err);
return (obj.error.decline_code);
```

Comment: Working with the JSON in that mangled format is a bandaid solution, and certainly not a good one. Do you have any control over the response? If so, change it so that it returns a valid JSON string - ideally with the error message INSIDE the JSON, not appended to the string. Then go and find the developer who wrote the code to create that output and give them a very firm slap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getting error beacause JSON.parse parses only jsons. Your err is nor a json because of the ' Your card is declined due to ' section.

```
// First you want to represent your err as a JSON object
var err = '{ "error": { "code": "card_declined", ///.../// "type": "card_error" } }';

// Now you can parse it
let obj = JSON.parse(err);
console.log(obj.error.decline_code); // Output: insufficient_funds
```

In addition if you want to keep your error structure you can do something like this:

```
const errIntro = 'Your card is declined due to '
console.log(errIntro + obj.error.decline_code); //Output: Your card is declined due to insufficient_funds
```

If you want a clearer answer you can even remove the '_' and you can also add a nice final point using:

```
const errorCode = obj.error.decline_code.replace(/_/g, ' ');
console.log(errIntro + errorCode + '.'); //Output: Your card is declined due to insufficient funds.
```

I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON so it needs to be valid

If it is impossible to fix this on the server (which it should) then you can do

```js
var err = `Your card is declined due to "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": \"card_declined\",\n    \"decline_code\": \"insufficient_funds\",\n    \"doc_url\": \"https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/card-declined\",\n    \"message\": \"Your card has insufficient funds.\",\n    \"param\": \"\",\n    \"request_log_url\": \"https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_fhgKiF9C0d1RrK?t=1700727296\",\n    \"type\": \"card_error\"\n  }\n}\n"`;

err = err.slice(`Your card is declined due to "`.length,-1)
console.log(err)
let obj = JSON.parse(err);
console.log(obj.error.decline_code);
```